# Ubuntu slow at boot because of gnome-set~ngs-daemon

Tags: boot, hard-drive, startup

When I boot my computer, the process gnome-set~ngs-daemon need a lot of disk access, according to sudo iotop, it require 100%...

Any idea how I can solve it?

Comment: The full name is gnome-settings-daemon. I have the same issue (apparently 2 years later). There is also and apt-cache dump-available using a lot of disk (20M/s for more than 10s) before gnome-settings-daemin does.